# Refresh data when day changes in offline app

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have an offline app that stores data in RoomDatabase. New data is inserted only after user action (when button is clicked or spinner selection changes). Data is retrieved as LiveData.
**In my main activity I am only showing data for current day. But my problem appears when day changes and app is still in the background, not killed by the system. In that situation, activity still shows data for previous day.
How I can implement refresh when current date is different from date showed in activity?**
When app was killed, I have a method in onCreate that tries to insert new row (with onConflict Ignore), and that works. But if there is better way, I am open for suggestions.

Dao (I am getting only row with date that matches passed date)

```
@Query("SELECT * from coffee_productivity WHERE date LIKE :todayDate")
fun getTodayData(todayDate: String): LiveData<CoffeeProductivityData>
```

Repository

```
private var mTodayData: LiveData<CoffeeProductivityData> = mCoffeeProductivityDao.getTodayData(mUtilities.getTodayDate())

// Wrapper for getting current day data
fun getTodayData(): LiveData<CoffeeProductivityData> {
    return mTodayData
}
```

ViewModel

```
private val mTodayData: LiveData<CoffeeProductivityData> by lazy {
    mRepository.getTodayData()
}

// Get LiveData for today coffees and productivity
fun getTodayData(): LiveData<CoffeeProductivityData> {
    return mTodayData
}
```

Comment: Could tell more information? What is date? It is like 'dd-mm-yyyy'. And why do you need to relate to date? Also `System.currentTimeMillis()` return always current date.

Comment: Date is stored in database as String (dd/mm/yyyy). I am getting current date using my utility method. I am getting it same way You showed.
My main activity is showing data for current day, so I am retrieving a row, where date matches my current date.
I think the problem is with the fact that my LiveData is observing same row when date changes but activity is not killed, so I need some way to refresh that observed row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AlarmManager`  to wake the phone at midnight and than call your method The

> AlarmManager API is another option that the framework provides for
>   scheduling tasks. This API is useful in cases in which an app needs to
>   post a notification or set off an alarm at a very specific time.

Source : [developer](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling)

Comment: Ok, so what would be best way to implement that LiveData refreshing?
Change to MutableLiveData and use setValue?

Comment: as long as your method doesn't change anything in the app UI you can use whatever you want, coz if you update the app layout while the app is closed or in the background, it will crash, but if u want to change background data or even save them in sharedpreferences than you have nothing to worry about